# What do we call a number transformation or function that outputs the input number without its decimal?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology, rational-numbers

This question is looking for any established terminology, function, transformation or whatever the generalized term is for transmuting one collection of things into the same or different collection of things, whereby the english definition of said process might be, "it removes the decimal point from the number".

As an example, imagine a function that operated on rational numbers that did not have trailing zeroes after the decimal and only had a finite number of digits after the decimal point.

$$f(4) = 4$$
$$f(4.2) = 42$$
$$f(34.10983) = 3410983$$
$$f(-44.34) = -4434$$

Does anything (function or no) like $f$ have a name that already exists?

If a computational example helps, this is how I might define this function in python:

```
def remove_decimal(num: float) -> int:
    float_string = str(num)
    assert not('.' in float_string and float_string[-1] == '0') # Makes trailing zeroes after a decimal illegal.
    return int(float_string.replace('.', ''))
```

Comment: You have to be careful about how you would define such a function. For example, what it would output if you plugged in $4.0$? If you say that $f(4.0)=40$ but $f(4)=4$, then $f$ is not a function. And of course, if $f$ is not well-defined, then it is unlikely to have a name.

Comment: Also, is $f(1230)=123$ or $f(1230)=1230$?

Comment: Seems that the function just "removes" the comma. It makes sense to choose the representation without trailing zeros. So , instead of $4.0$ , we use $4$ and integers are mapped to itself. This is at least how I would inteprete this function.

Comment: So we write the number as $n / 10^m$, where $10$ does not divide $n$, and then return $n$? Or return $n$ only if $m >0$ and otherwise return the number?

Comment: Since $f(n)=n$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ (yes?) the range is  exactly $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Please insert the question also in the text, not only in the title. Please define $f$. Please add the needed context to the question. For mantissa, significand, ... maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand first

Comment: @Joe Very good point, I perhaps left it a little vague on purpose, as the question is looking for already established functions/terminology and any implementation is fine. Even if it weren't a function, but the other one where an input can have multiple outputs I would still like to know.

Comment: @Troposphere $f(1230) = 1230$

Comment: @dan_fulea Were those edits satisfactory?

Comment: @lulu yes good point, but since that doesn't answer the spirit of the question, I've removed the bit asking about for the name of the range of $f$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog also choose $m$ to be as small as possible such that $n$ is still an integer.